# JavaScript not working in Firefox, Chrome - works in IE, Edge

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I made this script, that will put a filter on an images. But it only seems to work in Internet explore and in Microsoft Edge.

Can someone maybe guide me in the right direction, to get it working in Google chrome and Firefox?

```
<html>
<style>
h1 { font-size:2rem; }
p { font-size:1rem; }
canvas { display:block; margin:15px; }
button { margin:15px; }
img { display:block;}
</style>
<script>
function filter() {

  //canvas settings 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture");

  //matches the image size to the canvas
  canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

  //overfører billedet til canvas
  context.drawImage(img,0,0);

  //Loads data from the image   var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var data = imageData.data;

  //Runs all the pixel
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {

    //fetch the RGB values from the pixels 
    var red = data[i];
    var green = data[i + 1];
    var blue = data[i + 2];
    // på pladsen i+3 sidder alpha (gennemsigtigheden)

    //FILTER START

        //puts the avarage for red green and blue 
        imageData.data[i] = Math.round(red*0.5);
        imageData.data[i+1] = Math.round(green*0.5);
        imageData.data[i+2] = Math.round(blue*0.5);

    }

  // overrides the original image on the canvas 
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

}

</script>
<body>

  <div align="center">

      <h1>Use a filter</h1>

            <button onclick="filter()">Use filter</button>

      <img src="https://videnskab.dk/files/article_media/golden_gate_bridge.jpg" id='picture'>
       <canvas id="canvas"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello Phillip and welcome to Stackoverflow. Although you've told us there's a problem in Firefox/Chrome, you haven't provided any description of what goes wrong in these browsers.

Comment: check the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question so the community can help you better

Comment: Hello Spender
thank you. it loads the picture, and it goes through the filter. But the filter newer applies to the new picture.

Answer (score 0):

This is a crossorigin problem caused by running the webpage from the filesystem. To get round this, try running the page from a webserver, ensuring that the image is served from the same origin, or is served with the relevant CORS headers. Without this, `getImageData` will fail.

Running through a webserver should get you going again. I use https://fenixwebserver.com/ , a mini desktop webserver that you can point at local folders and start a static file web-server.

Comment: It worked. That is nice and simple, that I can run local.

Thank you for the help, you made my day :)